# LGPL v 2.1 + Linking Over Controlled Interface

Tags: lgpl

I use ([nrjavaserial](https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial))  library in a java application.

This library is released under the LGPL v 2.1 + Linking Over Controlled Interface license.

I have two questions:

- If the implementation falls under the Linking Over Controlled interface exception, do I still need to fulfill the LGPL part (allowing the user to replace the library).
- Assuming the above ponint is fullfilled, the license says "provided that every copy of the combined work is accompanied by a complete copy of the source code of RXTX" , do I need to provide the RXTX source code with every delivered copy of the softare or is it enough to provide it through a written offer?

Thank you